# How does wkhtmltopdf set the font of the generated pdf

Tags: java, wkhtmltopdf

I need to convert an html file into pdf, and the pdf font I need to generate is Microsoft YaHei. But I now encounter a problem: I cannot set the font of the generated PDF. No matter what font I set, the font in the resulting PDF remains the same as before. The following is my test code on Windows. I will need to implement the same function on Linux later.

```
    /**
     * html to pdf
     *
     * @param srcPath  html path, which can be a path on the hard disk or a network path
     * @param destPath pdf save path
     * @return Returns true if the conversion is successful
     */
    public static boolean convert(String srcPath, String destPath,String toPdfTool){
        File file = new File(destPath);
        File parent = file.getParentFile();
        // If the pdf save path does not exist, create the path
        if(!parent.exists()){
            parent.mkdirs();
        }
        StringBuilder cmd = new StringBuilder();
        cmd.append(toPdfTool);
        cmd.append(" ");
        cmd.append(" --encoding utf-8 ");
        cmd.append(" -O Landscape ");
        cmd.append(" --disable-smart-shrinking ");
        cmd.append(" --zoom 0.92 ");
        // No matter what font I set here, it seems to have no effect (Microsoft YaHei, Song Dynasty)
        cmd.append(" --header-font-name Segoe UI ");
        cmd.append(srcPath);
        cmd.append(" ");
        cmd.append(destPath);
        boolean result = true;
        try{
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toString());
            proc.waitFor();
        }catch(Exception e){
            result = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Please tell me what I need to do to ensure that the font of the generated PDF is Microsoft YaHei. Thank you very much.

Comment: I found that the English content in the html has the same font as the generated pdf, but the Chinese content in the pdf has the same font, and it is different from the font in the html